# Ruby on Rails Imagemagick picture is not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick

I'm using Imagemagick for uploading picture. I'm trying to desplay uploaded picture with:

```
<%= image_tag @book.picture.url(:small) %>
```

or without (:small).

But it only displays the name of the picture.

This is how my record book is saved:

```
    #<Book id: 27, title: "ccccc", genre: "fffff", language: "ccccc", 
format: nil, summary: "fgreqvger", rating: 0.0, source: "cccc", published:
 1234, created_at: "2016-01-17 16:43:00", updated_at: "2016-01-17 16:43:00", 
file_file_name: "filename.pdf", file_content_type: "application/pdf", 
file_file_size: 309205, file_updated_at: "2016-01-17 16:43:00", 
picture_file_name: "Colorful-Flat-PSD-Template-4.jpg", picture_content_type:
 "image/jpeg", picture_file_size: 73885, picture_updated_at: "2016-01-17 
16:43:00", author: nil>
```

Is there something wrong with picture_file_name? Or with path to image? I don't really see where the path is specified anyway. How do I know that rails is actually trying to display the right image or how do I know where the image is stored?

Comment: Can you browse to `public/system` and see if you can find the picture for us? If it's in there, it means the upload is okay, if not, it means there's something wrong with paperclip

Comment: It's there. in public/system/books/27/original/Colorful-Flat-PSD-Template-4.jpg

Comment: (27 is the id of the book)

Comment: okay so this is good news.

Comment: Have you tried just `@book.picture.url` ?

Comment: What happens if you output the following: `<%= @book.picture.url %>`

Comment: /system/books/pictures/000/000/027/original/Colorful-Flat-PSD-Template-4.jpg?1453048980

Comment: So it seems to be working... If you copy that `path` and paste into your browser` IE `localhost:3000/system/books/pictures/000/000/027/original/Colorful-Flat-PSD-Template-4.jpg?145‌​3048980` - what happens?

Comment: No need to mention the .url, you can directly call as `<%= image_tag @book.picture(:small) %>`

Comment: I get No route matches [GET] "/system/books/pictures/000/000/027/original/Colorful-Flat-PSD-Tem%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bplate-4.jpg"

Comment: Is the url even correct? why are those 000 there?

Comment: @Sasidaran thanks, but the output is the same. I still get just the name of the picture.

Comment: Means the picture hasn't been uploaded properly

Comment: Can you try uploading another image and seeing if the same thing happens? Imagemagick might have messed up the conversion

Comment: but it's there in the folder, just at different url... is it possible that only the url is stored wrong adn I can change it manually? For example that I concatenate a string with the correct path and store it instead of the wrong one?

Comment: May I know what is the `url` option configured in Book model for picture (has_attached_file :picture, url: ?)

Comment: It's the same with new picture. Could it be that maybe the route is not defined? I only have route for controller/action/id, should I have specified another route for pictures?

Comment: @Sasidaran this is in my model: has_attached_file :picture,  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"

Comment: should there be url instead of path? I don't really know how this things work so i just folow the tutorials, might have missed something out.

Comment: lol so many questions!!!!! Let me write an answer to help

Comment: both url and path needs to be defined for a paperclip attachment,. `url` is where the actual uploads will be saved and `path` is the default image location can be specified. Something like `:url => "/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename`.  So now new uploads will be saved to public/system/books/picture/:id/name...

Comment: sorry, i know. But I've spent so much time trying to figure out that picture upload and I really want to make it work :)

Comment: @Sasidaran oh, I didn't know that. So what should I write for path? I suppose this path I posted before was actually url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're looking for help, here's how to set up Paperclip:

```
#app/models/book.rb
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_attached_file :picture, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png", path: ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename", url: ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
  validates_attachment_content_type :picture, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Considering you have the db setup, the above should allow you to upload the file. Displaying it can be done as you already are; so the only thing I would suggest is *either* you've not got the `styles` option setup properly, or your imagemagick install is faulty.